# Weird while loop with an assignment operation C++

Tags: c++

I've seen the following snippet in a leetcode solution. It counts the number of elements in a linked list. The while statement just has an assignment operation. Can anyone explain how this works.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */

struct ListNode * temp = head;
int num = 1;
while(temp = temp->next){
    num++;
}
```

Comment: C++ assignments are expressions that evaluate to the value assigned...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Seems a decent answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. the value of `temp->next`is assigned to `temp`
2. `while(temp)` is evaluated (as `temp != NULL`)
3. in case the loop body is executed

Note: if `head` is NULL your program will face a runtime error

Comment: Might be worth adding a 1.5 explaining that you're looking at `while(temp)` because assignments get evaluated as the value that was assigned (which is the new temp, or `temp->next` depending on how you're looking at it).

Comment: If `head` is NULL, the behaviour is undefined.   It may or may not result in a runtime error.